# How to remove non-existent programs from the Apps & Features menu?

Tags: windows-10

[image]

It's been a while since I uninstalled the game, at least a year. For some reason, it still shows up in the Apps & Features menu. It's annoying me simply because the directory no longer exists, the program no longer exists, yet I can't purge it from the menu at all.

How to remove non-existent programs from the Apps & Features menu?

Comment: Have you tried looking for and removing the item(s) from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall ?  I would do a Registry search and remove the instance(s) from the Registry. Backup the keys before you delete them (1 by 1), that way if the Start menu stops working or something, you can _merge_ them back in. The items(s) were probably part of a package which tends not to remove them completely. A bug in the install feature of Windows Installer.

Comment: Have you tried to get a list of all the packages? Open POWERSHELL and type or paste by right-clicking, and maybe redirect it to a file? __Get-AppxPackage * >>C:\Windows\Temp\PACKAGE.TXT__  because the list will probably be very long. Then to remove a package in PowerShell __Get-AppxPackage *skypeapp* | Remove-AppxPackage__

Comment: Okay, I'll try your first solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One simple way is to use the "old" Programs and Features control panel to attempt to uninstall them.

When you attempt to remove them from here and the uninstaller cannot be found then it will ask if you simply want to remove the entry instead.

You can get to it using the link at the top of the "Apps & Features" window that you are currently using,

[image]

Answer (score 5):

the legacy control panel which is still in windows 11 offers the prompt to remove the program from the list which should solve the issue.

start > search for control panel > open > uninstall a program

Comment: They don't want to uninstall a program, they want to remove it from the list.

Comment: @Toto it will still prompt you to just remove the entry when it can't find the app installed on the system. It works in Win11 as it works on Win10, but the link to the control panel apps and features is missing in Win11, so you have to search for it using the search function instead. This answer is valid enough for someone who can't edit other answers. ;)

Comment: Quickest way to open the legacy app menu on any Windows version is to hit `Win`+`R`, type `appwiz.cpl` and hit enter.